# Command to output a pipenv lockfile into the requirements.txt file?

Tags: pipenv

> Note
>
> If you’d like a `requirements.txt` output of the lockfile, run
> `$ pipenv lock -r`. This will include all hashes, however
> (which is great!). To get a `requirements.txt` without hashes, use
> `$ pipenv run pip freeze`.

According to the above [pipenv notice](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html), if you’d like a `requirements.txt` output of the lockfile, you should run `$ pipenv lock -r`. However, the `-r` options does not exist:

```
$ pipenv lock -r
Usage: pipenv lock [OPTIONS]
Try 'pipenv lock -h' for help.
$ pipenv lock -h
Usage: pipenv lock [OPTIONS]

  Generates Pipfile.lock.

Options:
  --categories TEXT
  --dev-only             Emit development dependencies *only* (overrides
                         --dev)
  -d, --dev              Generate both develop and default requirements  [env
                         var: PIPENV_DEV]
  --extra-pip-args TEXT
  --pre                  Allow pre-releases.
  --python TEXT          Specify which version of Python virtualenv should
                         use.
  --clear                Clears caches (pipenv, pip).  [env var: PIPENV_CLEAR]
  -q, --quiet            Quiet mode.
  -v, --verbose          Verbose mode.
  --pypi-mirror TEXT     Specify a PyPI mirror.
  -h, --help             Show this message and exit.
```

May I know the command to get the `requirements.txt` output of the pipenv lockfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you have linked to is `pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html`. The official docs at https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile.html#pipfile-lock-security-features says:

> Generate requirements.txt output from lock file
>
> ```
> $ pipenv requirements
> ```

Comment: After running the above command in the terminal, the terminal showed the required packages and their version numbers but did not generate a `requirements.txt` file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It generates _output_. You need to redirect that output to `requirements.txt` (or whichever filename of your choosing).

Comment: So it should be `$ pipenv requirements > requirements.txt` or copy and paste the generated output of `$ pipenv requirements` into a `requirements.txt` located in the same directory as the `Pipfile.lock`.

Comment: Yes, that's about right.